# Unable to dual boot windows 8

Tags: boot, grub2, dual-boot, windows-8

I've tried to create a bootable USB using my `Windows 8` OS. When I boot from the USB it brings me to a `gns GRUB menu`. Its a black screen which tells me to `Try Ubuntu` or `Install`, or  to check for disc problems and something for manufacturers. I've tried all of these but it just comes to a black screen and no ubuntu installation screen appears. The same USB works fine when tried to dual boot with `Windows 7`.

Comment: Do you mean that it works fine dual booting Windows 7 on the same computer or not (that might have been the case in the past, for example)? If not, that doesn't mean Ubuntu supports the same hardware as in your other computer dual booting Win7.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with an Ubuntu 12.10 64bit usb install key. You don't give enough information to be sure, but for me it was impossible to boot anything from the USB without turning off Secure Boot in the bios (which makes sense - this is what Secure Boot is for!). Go into your bios, turn off secure boot, and give it a shot.